# a.exe terminal closes just after program execution stops

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, tdm-mingw, tdm-gcc

I have installed TDM-GCC compiler on my system. And I write my c programs in a text editor and save it with the .c extension and compile it using the gcc command in the MinGW terminal and as usual the a.exe file is created as a result of it but when I double click the a.exe file and open it a terminal appears displaying the output and this terminal closes as soon as the program execution is over.... How do I stop this terminal from closing as soon as the program is over??

Comment: Put `system("PAUSE");` or `getchar();` or something like that at last.

Comment: do not double click; run cmd.exe instead, then type a.exe

Comment: hasn't this been answered like 32430 times?